# Assigning a value to a variable from a structure

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, struct, turbo-c++

I want to assign a value to a globally declared variable that comes from a structure member.

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
char question[15];

struct place{
    char name[15];
    int length;
}aa={"Paris",5};

void places()
{
    question[15]=aa.name[15];

}

main()
{
    clrscr();
    places();
    cout<<question;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you clarify? BTW C++ != C.

Comment: `question[15]=aa.name[15];` --> `strcpy(question, aa.name);`

Comment: This is using a C++ style that has been obsolete for more than 15 years. You can get a modern compiler for free.

Comment: `#include<iostream.h>` --> `#include<iostream>`

Comment: Does this even compile? I believe it doesn't on a C++ compiler

Comment: `cout` --> `std::cout`

Comment: Turbo C++ is a 20+ year old antiquated compiler. Your school is poisoning your mind!

Comment: Global variables (your question array) are a grievous sin, and your program seems almost as if it were a textbook example of using them.  Get out that textbook and read the section on functions and their parameter lists.  I know you said that's what you were trying to do, but, well, it's better not to.

Comment: @WillBriggs - _Global variables (...) are a grievous sin_.  Globals have their place.  They are not always bad when used properly.

Comment: Shh!  They'll hear you!  (Or, if I should be more explicit:  beginners don't need to hear that.  Because the proper use is rare, and beginners are tempted to use them constantly.)

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly*** - You should stop using Turbo C++, it is no longer supported, and is an antiquated implementation of C++.  (you will learn bad coding technique)

Here is a place you can download a ***[free modern compiler _AND_ development environment](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/)*** all in one...,  ***[HERE](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/lunasr1)*** is another.

***Regarding your question***:
You cannot use the `=` operator to make char array assignments as you have tried in `places()`.  You need to become familer with the ***[string functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/)***.  For the assignment you are making in the `void places()` function, you can use `strcpy()`.

Change:

```
question[15]=aa.name[15];//Not correct.  The variables have already been 
                         //created, do not include array operator here `[]`
```

To:

```
strcpy(question, aa.name);
```